# SwiftUI animation affect inner objects

Tags: animation, swiftui

I have question.. if I have several views that has buttons etc elements inside and also has animation on parent view.
How I can avoid that animation affect inner objects. In my case all buttons catch delay from parent view.
I try to use **.сlipped**, but I helps only for **.shadow** option, not for animations ;)

**Example:**

```
ViewA(editAction: {

}).opacity(isShow ? 1 : 0)
.animation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.6).delay(0.8))

ViewB(editAction: {

}).opacity(isShow ? 1 : 0)
.animation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.6).delay(0.95))

ViewC(editAction: {

}).opacity(isShow ? 1 : 0)
.animation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.6).delay(1.1))
                            
ViewD(verified: .constant(true), editAction: {
                                
}).opacity(isShow ? 1 : 0)
.animation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.6).delay(1.25))
                            
ViewE(knowMoreAction: {
                                
}).opacity(isShow ? 1 : 0)
.animation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.6).delay(1.4))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link animation to dependent value explicitly, like

```
ViewE(knowMoreAction: {
                                
}).opacity(isShow ? 1 : 0)
.animation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.6).delay(1.4), value: isShow)
```